# Why is this solution about combinations correct?

Tags: combinatorics

This is Exercise 9 from Section 3.5 of *Book of Proof* by Hammock.

> This problem concerns lists of length 6 made from the letters A,B,C,D,E,F,
> without repetition. How many such lists have the property that the D occurs
> before the A?

I solved it, correctly, as follows:

- The case when D appears first in the list: $ \underline{1} \; \underline{5} \; \underline{4} \; \underline{3} \; \underline{2} \; \underline{1} = 120 $
- The case when D appears second in the list: $\underline{4} \; \underline{1} \; \underline{4} \; \underline{3} \; \underline{2} \; \underline{1} = 96$
- The case when D appears third in the list: $ \underline{4} \; \underline{3} \; \underline{1} \; \underline{3} \; \underline{2} \; \underline{1} = 72 $
- The case when D appears fourth in the list: $\underline{4} \; \underline{3} \; \underline{2} \; \underline{1} \; \underline{2} \; \underline{1} = 48 $
- The case when D appears fifth in the list: $  \underline{4} \; \underline{3} \; \underline{2} \; \underline{1} \; \underline{1} \; \underline{1} = 24 $

The sum is the answer: $ 120 + 96 + 72 + 48 + 24 = 360 $

However, the correct answer (that relates to combinations) is as follows:

> Begin with six blank spaces and select two of these spaces. Put the D in the first selected space and the A in the second. There are $ C(6, 2) = 15 $ ways of doing this. For each of these 15 choices there are 4! = 24 ways of filling in the remaining spaces. Thus the answer to the question is 15×24 = 360 such lists.

I **do not** understand why $ C(6,2) = 15 $ accounts for the possible combinations of $ A $ and $ D $, although I do understand the arithmetic behind it: $ \frac{6!}{2!(6-2)!} = \frac{30}{2} = 15 $. I thought $C(6,2)$ represented the possible non-repeated subsets of length $ k $ from a set with $ n $ elements. Therefore, would not C(6,2) include all elements of the set $ \{A, B, C, D, E, F, G\} $? Could someone explain this solution?

Comment: $\binom{6}{2}$ is the number of ways to choose two things from a collection of six (unordered, without repetition).  In this case, the collection is the collection of six possible positions into which to place the letters, and you are choosing two of them to hold the letters A and D.

Comment: As a general remark on the problem:  $D$ precedes $A$ exactly half the time, so the answer is $\frac {6!}2=360$.  Symmetry can be very powerful.

Comment: @JBL - thank you for the response. My next question is why does this problem use a combination instead of a permutation? Does not order matter in this case?

Comment: There is an even easier way: the set is exactly half of all orderings of the letters, without conditions.

Comment: And your answer is not incorrect, it is just harder than it has to be, as is the other answer.

Comment: The order in which you choose the first two positions (those for A and D) doesn't matter because you know that D has to go in the leftmost one and A has to go in the rightmost one.   There are many possible ways to approach this problem, another one would be to choose the four positions for B, C, E, F first, and if you thought about the problem that way then you would want to choose them *with* order (first choose a place for B, then choose a place for C, then choose a place for E, then choose a place for F).

Answer (score 2):

As @JBL said $6 \choose 2$ is the number of ways to choose two things from a collection of six this results in 15 possible ways to choose these spots:
$$ *\,*\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_$$
$$ *\,\_\,*\,\_\,\_\,\_$$
$$ \cdots $$
$$ \_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,*\,*$$
Now fill each of these 15 with $D$ before $A$
$$ D\,A\,\_\,\_\,\_\,\_$$
$$ D\,\_\,A\,\_\,\_\,\_$$
$$ \cdots $$
$$ \_\,\_\,\_\,\_\,D\,A$$
now for each of these 15 we can fill with $4!$ ways for the remaining spots
$$ D\,A\,4\,3\,2\,1$$
$$ D\,4\,A\,3\,2\,1$$
$$ \cdots $$
$$ 4\,3\,2\,1\,D\,A$$
thus we have $4! \cdot 15 = 360$ such lists.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Solution**

Let's count the number of list where letter D appear before A. Say $x_{1}$ letters appear before D, $x_{2}$ appear between D and A, and $x_{3}$ appear after A. These non-negative integers must follow the following relation:

$$
x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 4
$$

Easily solved through stars and bars (look it up if you are not familiar with it): $\binom{4+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{6}{2}$

Then you put the remaining letters in the available slots; $4\times 3\times 2\times 1=4!$. Therefore the total number of list is given by the multiplication rule $\binom{6}{2}\times 4!=360$

**Remark**

As others have pointed out, there are many others alternatives e.g. using symmetry as lulu mentioned, $\frac{6!}{2}=360$, or just like the solution in your book. Just be creative and try to find as many alternative solutions as possible.

However, one thing you shouldn't do is to list out many possibilities just like in your original answer. This typically only works for very simple and introductory problems. Listing out should only be used to find pattern, which you can then use to build a solution on.